# How to fadein and fadeout images one time only in jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
#wrap{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    background-color:black
}
#wrap img.bgfade{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-1
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
<img class="bgfade" src="images/s1.png">
<img class="bgfade" src="images/s2.png">
<img class="bgfade" src="images/s3.png">
<img class="bgfade" src="images/s4.png">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $('img.bgfade').hide();
    var dg_H = $(window).height();
    var dg_W = $(window).width();
    $('#wrap').css({'height':dg_H,'width':dg_W});
    function anim() {
        $("#wrap img.bgfade").first().appendTo('#wrap').fadeOut(2000);
        $("#wrap img").first().fadeIn(1000);
            setTimeout(anim, 3000);
                            //setInterval(anim, 3000);
    }

    anim();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to do smoke animation, I am having 4 images, the 4 smoke images should be fadein and fadeout but only once. after the fourth image fades out animation should not occur again. I have taken this code from this site http://demo.web3designs.com/jquery-animated-background-images-fade-in-out.htm. Kindly help me guys.

Comment: can you share the html as well

Answer (score 1):

don't know what you are trying to say but.. if you want it in load function then call it there only and remove setTimeout (i have no idea why are you using `setTimeout` if you don't need to call it again).

```
 $(window).load(function(){
   $('img.bgfade').hide();
   var dg_H = $(window).height();
   var dg_W = $(window).width();
  $('#wrap').css({'height':dg_H,'width':dg_W});

  anim();
});

 function anim() {
   $("#wrap img.bgfade").first().appendTo('#wrap').fadeOut(1500);
   $("#wrap img").first().fadeIn(1000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $imgs = $("#wrap img");

function anim() {
    var $current = $imgs.filter('.current').removeClass('current'),
        $next = $current.next();
    $next = $next.length ? $next : $imgs.first();
    $next.addClass('current');

    $current.fadeOut(1500);
    $next.fadeIn(1000);
    if (!$imgs.last().is($next)) {
        setTimeout(anim, 3000);
    }
}
anim();
```